# Time taken by ejabberd to mark a client offline

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack, ejabberd-api

I am using Smack library on android for implementing xmpp based chat. How much time does ejabberd server takes to mark a user offline (start storing into offline storage) if it receives a presence type=unavailable from a client.

Is it instant or does it takes some time?

Answer (score 0):

The presence is broadcasted in realtime, so yes, broadcasting presence unavailable is instant.

Comment: There is a web portal of ejabberd (host:5280/admin/), which shows the list of online users. There are instances when according to that list, a user is still online, but the messages meant to be delivered to this user are getting stored in offline storage (spool). Does this list takes a while to get updated?